# How to get each element text since he is first sibling of h3 ( all h3 in the page) and without class access [classes change from page to antoher]

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the the text i want to get from scraping, of course i want to get all the first divs that are an h3 first sibling 
[image]

Here is my code

```
def get_post_comments(self):
    REQUEST_URL = f'https://mbasic.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid={self.post_id}&id=415518858611168'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.parse_html(REQUEST_URL).content, "html.parser")
    comments = [comment.get('h3') for comment in soup.find_all('h3').next_sibling]

    print(comments)
```

I'm having multiple errors and i'm newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) `+`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<h3>title 1</h3>
<div class="ea">
    This text I want
    <br />
    ...
<div>
<div class="eax">
    ...
<div>

<h3>title 2</h3>
<div class="fa">
    This is also text I want
    <br />
    ...
<div>
<div class="fax">
    ...
<div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for div in soup.select("h3 + div"):
    print(div.contents[0].strip())
```

Prints:

```
This text I want
This is also text I want
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to exclude None or Null elements, itt doesn't work when there None Callable Objects

Comment: @Moooooooun Make sure that required elements are acutally there: do `print(soup)` Some elements may be injected via JavaScript and beautifulsoup doesn't "see them"